# How to not mix html/js with php in classes (mustache)

Tags: php, html, mustache

I have simple question - how to not mix html and js in php classes ?

I have CMS system which is made on Custom MVC framework (autoloader, router, event dispatcher and mustache template engine)

I have extensions (modules) and they are executed in BaseController construct method... The extensions works well without problems, but i mix html/js with php in them and i don't know how to proceed to fix this. I want to submit some day the CMS in codecanyon and i want to follow good practices...

I give you some examples:

Extension:

```
<?php
/**
 * ../../ext/pok4/email_subscribe/ext.php
 *
 * @package default
 */


if (count(get_included_files()) == 1) exit("Direct access not permitted."); //Don't edit
//Your Extension Script
class Email_Subscribe extends \App\Controllers\BaseController  {



    /**
     *
     */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->ext_html_position = 'up'; //up or down is valid value for this, you can place it div on top or bottom of your site

        //LANGUAGE SETTER
        if (get_current_language() == 'bg') {
            $this->lang= array_merge($this->lang, [
                    'ext_email_subscribe_welcome'=>'Здравей! Можеш да се абонираш за нашите новини като напишеш емейла си по-долу',
                    'ext_email_subscribe_button'=>'Абонирам се',
                    'ext_email_subscribe_enter'=>'Въведи емейл',
                    'ext_email_subscribe_denied'=>'Отказвам се',
                ]);
        }
        if (get_current_language() == 'en') {
            $this->lang= array_merge($this->lang, [
                    'ext_email_subscribe_welcome'=>'Hello! You can subscribe for our news, just type your email below',
                    'ext_email_subscribe_button'=>'I subscribe',
                    'ext_email_subscribe_enter'=>'Write your email',
                    'ext_email_subscribe_denied'=>'Refuse',
                ]);
        }
        if (get_current_language() == 'ru') {
            $this->lang= array_merge($this->lang, [
                    'ext_email_subscribe_welcome'=>'Привет! Вы можете подписаться на наши новости, написав свой адрес электронной почты ниже',
                    'ext_email_subscribe_button'=>'Подписаться',
                    'ext_email_subscribe_enter'=>'Введите адрес электронной почты',
                    'ext_email_subscribe_denied'=>'Я отказываюсь',
                ]);
        }
        if (get_current_language() == 'es') {
            $this->lang= array_merge($this->lang, [
                    'ext_email_subscribe_welcome'=>'¡Hola! Puede suscribirse a nuestras noticias, simplemente escriba su correo electrónico a continuación',
                    'ext_email_subscribe_button'=>'Yo suscribo',
                    'ext_email_subscribe_enter'=>'Escribe tu correo electrónico',
                    'ext_email_subscribe_denied'=>'Rehusar',
                ]);
        }
        //debug
        //var_dump($this->lang['ext_email_subscribe_welcome']);
        //var_dump($this->lang['ext_email_subscribe_button']);



    }



    /**
     *
     */
    public function load() {


        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' && (!isset($_COOKIE['argos_mail_subscribe_denied']) || !isset($_COOKIE['argos_email_subscribe_ok']))) {
            $this->dispatcher->emit('core_event_head_append', ['<link rel="stylesheet" href="ext/pok4/email_subscribe/css/style.css">']);

            if(get_style() == 'orizon' || get_style()== 'revelio') {
                $this->dispatcher->emit('core_event_head_append', ['<link rel="stylesheet" href="ext/pok4/email_subscribe/css/past.css">']);
            }

            $format_html_for_js = preg_replace('~>\s+<~', '><', addslashes(
                    '<section class="home-newsletter">
                    <div class="container" style="margin-top:0 !important">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="single">
                        <h2>'.$this->lang['ext_email_subscribe_welcome'].'</h2>
                        <form method="post">
                        <div class="input-group">
                             <input type="email"name="subscriber_email" class="form-control get_email_for_sub" placeholder="'.$this->lang['ext_email_subscribe_enter'].'">
                             <span class="input-group-btn">
                             <button class="btn btn-theme" name="send_email_sub" type="submit">'.$this->lang['ext_email_subscribe_button'].'</button>
                             </span>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="denied_email_sub center-block text-center"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"><button type="button" class="btn-close float-button-close" aria-label="Close"></button>&nbsp;<span style="color:red">'.$this->lang['ext_email_subscribe_denied'].'</span></a></div>
                    </section>'
                ));


            if ($this->ext_html_position =='up') {
                $send_div = 'prependTo("body");';
            } else {
                $send_div = 'appendTo("body");';
            }

            $this->dispatcher->emit('core_event_inside_head_ready_front', ['

             var cookie_check = getCookie("argos_email_subscribe_ok");
             var cookie_check2 = getCookie("argos_mail_subscribe_denied");
             if(cookie_check == null  && cookie_check2 == null) {
                 $("'.$format_html_for_js.'").'.$send_div.'

             } else {
                $(".home-newsletter").remove();
             }


             //Detect on click
             $( ".denied_email_sub" ).click(function() {
                  document.cookie=\'argos_mail_subscribe_denied=1;expires=Wed, 31 Oct 3099 08:50:17 GMT;path=/\';
                  $(".home-newsletter").remove();
             });

            ']);

            //submit form
            if (isset($_POST['send_email_sub'])) {
                $user_ip = $this->user_ip;
                $email = $_POST['subscriber_email'];

                //check if email exists
                $checker =  $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$this->argos_db_prefix."emails WHERE email=?");
                $checker->bindParam(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $checker->execute();
                if ($checker->rowCount() < 1) {
                    //send data to db
                    $go = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$this->argos_db_prefix."emails (`email`,`user_ip`) VALUES(?,?)");
                    $go->bindParam(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $go->bindParam(2, $user_ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $go->execute();
                }
                //send cookie to user to prevent box showing
                setcookie('argos_email_subscribe_ok', '1', time()+60*60*24*365, '/');
            }


        }
    }


};




$load_ext = new Email_Subscribe;
$load_ext->load();
```

Event dispatcher:

```
$dispatcher->on('core_event_inside_head_ready_front', function($data) {
  global $event_dispatcher;

  $template_event_name = "template_event_inside_head_ready_front";
  if(isset($event_dispatcher[$template_event_name]))  {
    $event_dispatcher[$template_event_name] .= $data;
  } else {
    $event_dispatcher[$template_event_name] = $data;  
  }
});
```

my template engine is mustache - https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php
My event dispatcher is: https://github.com/igorw/evenement

i want to have custom templates in this class above.. which is worked with ajax post/get/json and post/get queries (from forms)

Maybe something like addon to mustache to render this files.. i don't know..
I look at this - https://github.com/avplab/php-html-builder (but i think that is not my solution)
I want to have custom files for every extension.
The extensions is made from 3 files (ext.php,sql.php and migrate.php)
This one above not have namespaces, but that is not problem - i can add, if is needed.
I use robot autoloader from github and it works well for every type of namespaces in my root dir...

Please, help me.. I want to separate html/js from php in pleasant way...

If you ask for more code - please, write...